# Should I flag answers which only improve syntax as 'Not an answer'?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer

Re. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138900/why-is-my-jquery-hide-not-working), and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30138916/519413) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30138951/519413); Note that one of the answers have since been deleted by the user, so you may need the required rep to view it.

The code given in the question worked correctly when tested, so the error cannot be diagnosed from the information given. The answer was then posted which improved the syntax and reduced verbosity of the OPs code, but would have made no difference to the outcome.

In this scenario is it valid to flag the answer as 'Not an answer'?

It would appear so, given that it would not help either the OP nor any future visitor to the question (even after the OP has found the issue and updated the question itself) - however it does help to educate others about logic improvements which could be made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't think so.

Not an answer flags are for answers that post php code to a c++ question.

The answers you link to try to answer the question. If they are not useful, downvote. Not An Answer flags should not be used to indicate technical incorrectness or unusefulness of an answer.

Also see the [Answer in some Castle post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You should comment that it does not try to answer the question, and what it does instead, as well as downvote it and delete-vote if possible.

Now, there's a reason you should not flag it NAA:
**It is not obvious enough!**

Instead, use a custom flag and concisely and comprehensively make that case to get it removed.

Anyway, OP deleted the question after getting an answer in the comments, so it's a moot point by now.